# Can’t Run Pydio Locally

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, pydio

The company where I work at has a slightly modified backoffice done in Pydio 8.0.1 up and running in the server.

Thing is I want to run it locally in Xampp to test if it works well alongside the new website I made for the company.

My problem is that I can’t get it running locally even though I have the database running in PHP MyAdmin. The errors that I get are:

**Deprecated** : Function create_function() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice2\core\src\lib\dibi\libs\DibiConnection.php on line 120
Fatal error : Uncaught Pydio\Core\Exception\PydioException: Severe error while loading plugins registry : There was an error trying to connect to your database! Did you change any configuration for the core connection? Or maybe your database is down? in C:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice2\core\src\pydio\Core\PluginFramework\PluginsService.php:819 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice2\core\src\pydio\Core\PluginFramework\PluginsService.php(203): Pydio\Core\PluginFramework\PluginsService->getDetectedPlugins() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice2\core\src\pydio\Core\Services\ConfService.php(392): Pydio\Core\PluginFramework\PluginsService::getInstance(Object(Pydio\Core\Model\Context)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice2\core\src\pydio\Core\Http\Base.php(62): Pydio\Core\Services\ConfService::getGlobalConf(‘ADMIN_URI’) #3 [internal function]: Pydio\Core\Http\Base::handleRoute(’/backoffice2’, ‘/’, Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice2\core\src\pydio\Core\Http\TopLevelRouter.php(139): call_user_func(Array, ‘/backoffice2’, ‘/’, Array) #5 C:\xamp in C:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice2\core\src\pydio\Core\PluginFramework\PluginsService.php on line 819

By the Way I noticed that the “Bootstrap.json” has the following custom lines:

**“AJXP_CLI_SECRET_KEY”:“vkkhh$lskdNyoNpi$B4Gc5DN”,
“DIBI_PRECONFIGURATION”:{
“mysql_username”:“hardlevel_pt”,
“mysql_use_mysqli”:“true”,
“mysql_password”:“ubukN4g8”,
“mysql_host”:“hardlevel.pt.mysql”,
“mysql_driver”:“mysql”,
“mysql_database”:“hardlevel_pt”,
“group_switch_value”:“mysql”
}**

Can anyone give me some insight on this situation? Any help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: are you using PHP 7.2 on your local machine? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php .

Comment: Regarding the second error, we can only suggest that you check that your database connection details and credentials are correct (e.g. correct server name/IP address, valid username/password/db name). We can't verify that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's problem of php version on Pydio 8.0.1
Try to upgrade to latest version of Pydio if you are using PHP 7.2